# Change Colors in Ng-Select

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ngselect

I have tried using ng-select and i encountered some problem. 
How can i change the disabled color in ng-select when i try to disabled it. And i want also the arrow icon to be hidden when it is disabled? I have tried this code below and it still won't work.

> Change disabled color

```
.ng-select.ng-select-red {
  color: green;
  background-color: green;
}
```

> Hide Arrow When Disabled

```
.ng-select:disabled.ng-arrow {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following selectors:

```
.ng-select.ng-select-disabled>.ng-select-container {
  background-color: red;
}

.ng-select.ng-select-disabled .ng-arrow-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```